# What do the scriptures say about the qualities of an ideal bride?

Tags: marriage, women

According to the Shastras - are there any qualities of an woman that should be kept in mind, by a man before taking the decision of marriage?

Answer (score 9):

Yes there are such references in Manu Smriti and several other scriptures.

From Manu Smriti:

> 3.8. Let him not marry a maiden (with) reddish (hair), nor one who has a redundant member, nor one who is sickly, nor one either with no hair
> (on the body) or too much, nor one who is garrulous or has red (eyes),
>
> 3.9. Nor one named after a constellation, a tree, or a river, nor one bearing the name of a low caste, or of a mountain, nor one named after
> a bird, a snake, or a slave, nor one whose name inspires terror.
>
> 3.10. **Let him wed a female free from bodily defects, who has an agreeable name, the (graceful) gait of a Hamsa or of an elephant, a
> moderate (quantity of) hair on the body and on the head, small teeth,
> and soft limbs.**

The above verses tell us which are the maidens whom one should marry and also which are the ones who are not that much recommended for the purpose.

The following verse also gives us few more such "negative" qualities of the bride.

> 3.11. But a prudent man should not marry (a maiden) who has no brother, nor one whose father is not known, through fear lest (in the
> former case she be made) an appointed daughter (and in the latter)
> lest (he should commit) sin.

Comment: Wow... Hinduism seems like an extremely tolerant religion with regards to gingers, those with disabilities, and those from other socioeconomic backgrounds...

Comment: In Hinduism diseases, physical deformities are taken as marks of sins committed in the previous births. But that does not mean such people are to be treated badly and they are not. Hinduism is extremely tolerant. @Persistence

Comment: I would argue that suggesting someone should not be married as a result of something beyond their control counts as treating them badly... Oh well, this isn't the forum for moral debate, I just felt the need to make my feelings known.

Comment: But the deeds that they did in the previous births were certainly under their control and the disease etc in the current birth is the outcome. You may be knowing tht the fundamental belief of Hinduism is the rebirth and Karma doctrine. So, all of that shd be understood as well while reading verses like the ones given in the answer. @Persistence

Comment: I do understand that. However, just because you believe it doesn't make it true.

Comment: We don't discuss what is true and what is not (from the universal or absolute perspective ) here.. We simply discuss what is the view of Hinduism on the topic being asked in the question. Here Hindu scriptures are taken as the authority. @Persistence

Comment: "should not marry (a maiden) who has no brother" – I wonder if any Hindus really follow this even today.  "negative" – wow, you putting negative in double quotes, so personally you don't think they are negative qualities?

Comment: I gave the double quotes because those qualities are not exactly the girl's traits but rather they focus on how her family is. @sv. So, they are not exactly the girl's negative features whn compared to the features mentioned earlier in the answer.